# can't append schema to empty dataframe with spark 2.0.0 Java 1.8

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I tried to create an empty Dataframe with spark 2.0.0 and Java 1.8. I then want to append a schema. After this i would like to insert content with SQL insert statements.

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> emptyDataset = null;
    try {
        //This part is still working:
    emptyDataset = sparkSession.emptyDataFrame();
        //This part has no effect at all:
    emptyDataset.schema().add("id", DataTypes.IntType)
                          .add("date", DataTypes.DateType)
                          .add("type", DataTypes.StringType);
    } catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Nope");
}
System.out.println("Schema:");
emptyDataset.printSchema();
```

And I get this, but no Schema:

```
Schema:
root
```

Any ideas, or what is wrong?
thx!